# Why can't the Omega Key be found like the Anywhere Key was?

Tags: locke-and-key, joe-hill

Disclaimer: I've only read up to Volume IV. Spoilers up-to and including.

In Vol. I,. the Anywhere Key is discovered when

> Bode, using the Ghost Key, can simply "think" himself to its location.

But for the next three volumes, Dodge is searching for the Omega Key. He should have no difficulty doing precisely the same thing:

> - He has possession of the Ghost Key, and uses it (in Vol. III).
>
>   The Omega Key is inside Keyhouse, in Rendell's urn, and so it should be find-able using the key.

Why, then, is Dodge stuck searching for so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I think it worked is that the key was destroyed when Rendell was cremated. It was only fixed when Nina Locke placed Rendell's ashes in the mending cabinet.

Answer (score 2):

Dodge won't risk becoming a ghost & leaving his body unattended for Sam's ghost to occupy.

Comment: Hmmm. That sounds reasonable. And yet - he does precisely that in _The Haunting of Keyhouse_, at the beginning of Volume III. And if that's the only reason, then turning Sam into a ghost in Vol. I seems like a really, really silly move. (This would also cease to be a problem after Vol. IV's finale - maybe it is; I haven't read vol. V yet...)